# The $n$th prime number is $85489307341$. How to find $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Say you are given the $n$th prime number $p_n$, like $p_n = 85489307341$, but not $n$.

**Questions:**

1. What's a quick, simple, and approximate formula for $n$?
2. By adding more terms, can this formula be made more precise?

***Edit*:** In reference to the answer below, how can we tweak $n = \pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log(x)}$ to make it more accurate?

Comment: is this really a prime number?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner [Yes.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+85489307341+prime)

Comment: Many good approximations are given on [wikipedia about prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Comment: One could [potentially win $1 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers) by answering your new question, so...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I don't mean tweak it _perfectly_. I'll be happy with a slight improvement. For example, as in the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) given by qwr, we have more terms as,  $$\frac{p_n}{n} \approx \ln(n) + \ln\ln n - 1 $$ or better, $$\frac{p_n}{n} \approx \ln(n) + \ln\ln n - 1 +\frac{\ln\ln n - 2}{\ln n}$$ Using these, how do we isolate $n$ and express it in terms of $p_n$?

Comment: A quick search with Mathematica produced $n=3\,543\,419\,187$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Care to share the command you used?  :)

Comment: See [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @Lucian: Feel free to answer if you can, using the _Lambert W function_,  isolate $n$ and express it in terms of $p_n$. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: If you enter ${\tt PrimePi[85489307341]}$ you obtain ${\tt 3\,543\,419\,187}$, and if you then enter ${\tt Prime[3543419187]}$ as a check you obtain the number you started with. – I think that Mathematica has a lot of such pairs in its memory and then starts a search upon entering an arbitrary $k$.

Comment: The question now basically is what are good approximations for the prime counting function. This is very classical and quite broad. You should at least specify what you care about: asymptotics or "it works well for 20-digit numbers" or what.

Comment: @quid I believe it is more like "given a decent approximation for $n = \pi(x)$, express $n$ in terms of $p_n$

Comment: @Ant  The questions ask to determine $n$ given $p_n$. Now the point is $n=\pi(p_n)$. This is the observation made in an answer. So just take your favorite approx. formula for $\pi(x)$ and take $x=p_n$. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
say nth_prime(3543419187)
85489307341

say prime_count(85489307341)
3543419187  # looks right
```

Note that prime counts at this size are quite cheap.  About 19 milliseconds on my laptop.  That's still over 1000x slower than the most complicated of the approximations below.

Percent difference from exact answer for various methods using this n, given in order of closeness for larger inputs:

$R(n)$  2.3e-7  very good approximation from Riemann's R function

${\rm li}(n)-{\rm li}(n^{0.5})/2$  1.7e-7  also very good from truncated R

${\rm li}(n)$  3.4e-6  very good

$(\pi_{\rm upper}(n)+\pi_{\rm lower}(n))/2$  9.5e-7  surprisingly good from average bounds, but it is all dependent on using tight bounds, and it doesn't keep up as size increases

$n/(\log(n)-1-1/\log(n))$  .00024  not horrible

$n/(\log(n)-1)$  .0019  meh

$n/\log(n)$  .042  ugh (but better than randomly guessing numbers)

Comment: Oh, come on, almost 1000 reputation points and still not formatting your posts with MathJax?

Comment: Happier?  I think the lack of tables or tabs is a bigger issue.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), you have for large $x$ that the number of primes less than or equal to $x$ is $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log(x)}$

Comment: This is a good way to put it.

Comment: Ah, the [prime counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) $\pi(x)$. Know a way to tweak this formula to make it more sharp?

Comment: Although you never know enough in math, I think that if there were some refinement of the formula $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{log(X)}$ , it would be quite known.

Comment: @Piquito: $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ is _much_ sharper than $x/\log x.$

Comment: Thank you, I have seen once about Li(x) but I have forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Much better, and given in the Wikipedia article is $$\pi(x )\approx Li(x) =\int_2^x \frac 1{\log t} \ dt$$

Comment: $$\pi(x) = 3543419187\\ \text{Li}(x) \approx 3543431315\\ \frac{x}{\ln x} \approx 3396252652$$ As in the first answer, can we add more terms to make $\text{Li}(x)$ even more accurate?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Probably not. It seems that the next term is oscillatory. In any case the oscillatory component is at least $\Theta_\pm(\sqrt x)/\log^kx$ where $k$ is some constant I forgot (maybe 2).

Comment: Note that $\pi(x)$ and $Li (x)$ are very close. It is known that which is higher changes infinitely many times, so the error does oscillate.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the nice approximations for $p_n / n$ in terms of $n$ (from Wikipedia's [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) entry, say) and invert it iteratively.  For instance, start with
$$
p_n \approx n \left(\log n + \log\log n - 1 +\frac{\log\log n - 2}{\log n}\right). 
$$
Initialize $n_0=p_n$.  And then iterate:
$$
n_{i+1}=\frac{p_n}{\log n_i + \log\log n_i - 1 + \frac{\log\log n_i - 2}{\log n_i}}.
$$
This converges nicely if $p_n$ is large... in your case I find $n\approx 3.5431\times 10^9$, which differs from the exact answer of $n=3543419187$ by about $0.01\%$.

Comment: This is quite indirect. The approach via the prime counting function seems superior.